# Search associative array of arrays. How?

Tags: php, arrays

My question is how can I search an array built this way? Basically there may be a need to repeat the key and this is what I got so far to maybe solve this. If the price is the same for 2 different items I cannot have 2 keys with the same value.

Please feel free to improve on array layout.

```
$price_list = array(
  1 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRVD"),
  2 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRV")
);
```

Comment: what information are you trying to store in an array?

Comment: basically you will need to iterate through the array, then through each of its arrays, try to explain below. Also when you say two keys with the same value, which key?  the first array key or the inner arrays? So 1 and 2 cannot have the same key value so the example above basically is not allowed as array 1 and 2 have the same inner array key value? can you add a few more to the array that are the opposite

Comment: What are you wanting to do? Find duplicate values for the first value in the child arrays? Or just search for the keys that contain the value 9.99?

Comment: I wanna for example search for EA_WTRESRVD and return 9.99. Can array_search do this? If so, can you provide an example with this type of array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided there will never be any duplication of the second column, you can do this:

```
$search = "EA_WTRESRVD"; //value to search for

$price_list = array(
  1 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRVD"),
  2 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRV")
);

$array = array_column($price_list, 0, 1);
echo $array[$search];
```

Comment: This as answer because precisely suits my needs. I love everyone's answers. Such rich content in one post on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that if you have a unique product code (SKU), you should use this to index your array.

```
$products = [
    'EA_WTRESRVD' => [
        'name'  => '...',
        'price' => 9.99,
        // ...
    ],
    'EA_WTRESRV' => [
        'name'  => '...',
        'price' => 9.99,
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Then you can access the price of any product by it's SKU.

```
$price = $products['EA_WTRESRV']['price'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
<?php

$price_list = [  1 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRVD"),
                 2 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRV")];

$search = "EA_WTRESRV";


foreach ($price_list as $arr) {
  if (in_array( $search, $arr )) {
        echo $search;
  }
}
```

The foreach iterates over the multidimensional array whose elements are each arrays.  Each array is inspected by in_array() for the search term.

However, this is not the only way.  If you wish to avoid in_array(), you could also code as follows:

```
<?php

$price_list = [  1 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRVD"),
                 2 => array("9.99", "EA_WTRESRV")];

$search = "EA_WTRESRV";
$len = strlen($search);


foreach ($price_list as $arr) {
  $val = array_values($arr);

  foreach($val as $v) {
     if ( ( strpos( $v,$search )) !== false) {
        if ( strlen($v) == $len) {
             echo "$search is in the price list.\n";
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed you're using [ ] instead of Array(). Is there a reason?

Comment: @Vim: it's perfectly legitimate PHP code nowadays and is convenient to use the short-array syntax.

Comment: Awesome! I always ask when I don't know. Thanks!